# Merge two dataframes based upon matching index to update other columns in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

w = pd.Series(['BAIN', 'BAIN', 'BAIN', 'KPMG', 'KPMG', 'KPMG', 'EY', 'EY', 'EY' ])
x = pd.Series([101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109])
y = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
z = pd.Series(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''])
a = pd.Series(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''])
longdf = pd.DataFrame({'consultant': w, 'invoice_number':x, 'paid_value':y, 'manager':z, 'department':a})

w = pd.Series(['BAIN', 'KPMG', 'EY', 'EY' ])
x = pd.Series([101, 104, 107, 108])
y = pd.Series([13000, 14000, 15000, 16000])
z = pd.Series(['Dawn', 'Brody', 'Tang', 'Vos'])
a = pd.Series(['Data Science', 'Automation', 'Sourcing', 'Sourcing'])
shortdf = pd.DataFrame({'consultant': w, 'invoice_number':x, 'paid_value':y, 'lead_manager_name':z, 'department_num':a})

combo = longdf.merge(shortdf, on = ['consultant', 'invoice_number'], how = 'left')
indexer = ['consultant', 'invoice_number']

shortdf = shortdf.set_index(indexer).rename(columns={'lead_manager_name':'manager', 'department_num':'department'})
longdf = longdf.set_index(indexer)
new = longdf.update(shortdf, join = 'left')
```

The goal would be to only update in longdf where the index matches the index of shortdf. I attached the goal below.[image]

Comment: Make it more obvious what we are starting with, what you want, and what you've tried.  There's an answer.  I just don't know which one you need.

Comment: Matching the index I want to be able to replace the value within longdf with the shortdf value for manager, department, and paid value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is pandas.merge. Should be looking like this?

```
#Output
Consultant  invoice_number  paid_value  lead_manager_name   department_num

0   BAIN        101           13000.0          Dawn          Data Science
1   BAIN        102           13000.0          Dawn          Data Science
2   BAIN        103           13000.0          Dawn          Data Science
3   KPMG        104           14000.0          Brody         Automation
4   KPMG        105           14000.0          Brody         Automation
5   KPMG        106           14000.0          Brody         Automation
6   EY          107           15000.0          Tang          Sourcing
7   EY          108           16000.0          Vos           Sourcing
8   EY          109           16000.0          Vos           Sourcing
```

Then here is the code:

```
cols_to_use= ["consultant","invoice_number"]
joint = pd.merge(longdf[cols_to_use],shortdf,on=cols_to_use,how="left").ffill()
joint
```

Comment: the goal would be to only update in longdf where the index matches shortdf.

Comment: By index you mean invoice number?

Comment: sorry, by index I meant = index = [consultant, invoice_number]